# Python application that uses image drawn on the screen by a user

Tags: python, user-interface

I used Python for different tasks but never for programming GUI. I would like to ask which Python libraries you would suggest for my task.

I am working on a Python application in which a user would see a GUI with:

- space on which they could draw an image using mouse (similarly as in Paint)
- button

When the button is pressed image created by the user would be read an converted to pixels and used by the application to return numeric result. The image would be a curve and not a straight line.

The majority of the answers talk about drawing images in the program and not by the user.
I also learnt about pygame which could be used for graphical interface. Would you suggest better option?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Check out the `tkinter` module, which comes builtin with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use PyQt or PySide if you want to build a UI with Image display on screen.

here is one example that uses `QPixmap` to display image on `QLabel`

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):      

    hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("redrock.png")

    lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

    hbox.addWidget(lbl)
    self.setLayout(hbox)

    self.move(300, 200)
    self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')
        self.show()        

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

here is pygame example

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True
        self._display_surf = None
        self._image_surf = None

    def on_init(self):
        pygame.init()
        self._display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode((350,350), pygame.HWSURFACE)
        self._running = True
        self._image_surf = pygame.image.load("myimage.jpg").convert()

    def on_event(self, event):
        if event.type == QUIT:
            self._running = False
    def on_loop(self):
        pass
    def on_render(self):
        self._display_surf.blit(self._image_surf,(0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()

    def on_cleanup(self):
        pygame.quit()

    def on_execute(self):
        if self.on_init() == False:
            self._running = False

        while( self._running ):
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                self.on_event(event)
            self.on_loop()
            self.on_render()
        self.on_cleanup()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    theApp = App()
    theApp.on_execute()
```

But i am not pygame expert!! this is the most basic i can do!